# Match tuple error expected String but found Option<<generic #5>>

Tags: rust

I'm having this error I can't seem to understand when dealing with match in a function, so currently I have of string tuples: `let mut bitmap_point: Vec<(&str, &str)> = vec![];` and I want to use this in a function `convert_to_binary`, so I declared this:

```
fn convert_to_binary_string(tup: &(&str,&str) ) -> String{
  let mut stringval: String =
  match tup {
    &(x,y) => from_str(x)
  };
  return stringval;
}
```

however upon calling the function with

```
let h = convert_to_binary_string( bitmap_point.get(0) );
```

I get the error :

```
>rustc main.rs
main.rs:12:3: 14:4 error: mismatched types: expected `collections::string::String` but found `core::option::Option<<generic #5>>` (expected struct collections::string::String but found enum core::option::Option) 
main.rs:12   match tup {
main.rs:13     &(x,y) => from_str(x)
main.rs:14   };
main.rs:13:15: 13:23 error: cannot determine a type for this bounded type parame
ter: unconstrained type
main.rs:13     &(x,y) => from_str(x)
                         ^~~~~~~~
```

could anyone explain what I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re going about this the wrong way. If you merely want to convert a `&str` (a string slice) into a `String` (an owned strng), you should use the [`.to_string()` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/to_str/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) or [`String::from_str(str)`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.from_str).

The `FromStr` trait is based around the `Option` type for conversions where not all inputs have a valid output—e.g. `from_str::<int>("four")` will return `None` because it can only cope with number literals. Where you’re turning something into a string, there are no failure cases, and `from_str(str).unwrap()` is a messy way of doing it.

Here is more idiomatic code to achieve your goal (using [`ref1()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/tuple/trait.Tuple2.html#tymethod.ref1)):

```
fn convert_to_binary_string(tup: &(&str, &str)) -> String {
    tup.ref1().to_string()
}
```

This could easily be rewritten without `ref1()` using matching, as you have done, or a simple `let` binding:

```
fn convert_to_binary_string(tup: &(&str, &str)) -> String {
    let &(x, _) = tup;
    x.to_string()
}
```

But as a general rule, you should probably not be using tuples anyway—it’s normally a better idea to use a structure with meaningfully named fields, e.g.

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
    y: &'a str,
}
```

… then it would have been

```
fn convert_to_binary_string(foo: &Foo) -> String {
    foo.x.to_string()
}
```

And at that stage you can probably drop the method altogether.

Comment: so, `from_str()` and `String::from_str()` are different functions? thanks for the detailed answer, this helped a **ton**

Comment: Yeah, [`from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/from_str/fn.from_str.html) is a simple convenience wrapper of [`FromStr::from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/from_str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer just took a simple documentation search and I found the answer, my issue was that `from_str(&str)` return `-> Option<T>` where the value could either be `Some` or `None`. This was why I was receiving the Option error as shown above.

To fix this I checkout out rust's documentation and found a function `unwrap()` which could pull `T` out of the option variable. Everything works as expected and my final function is:

```
fn convert_to_binary_string(tup: &(&str,&str) ) -> String{
  let mut stringval: String =
  match tup {
    &(x,y) => from_str(x).unwrap()
  };
  return stringval;
}
```